# Stream database systems

Tags: database, stream

I search information about stream database systems. I found only articles from 2002 to 2004 years.

For example the project http://infolab.stanford.edu/stream/ has wound down.

Does anyone known something currently on this topic?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

You should look for [time series database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database).
Hope time series database suits your requirement.